# What features should I use for predicting the performance of soccer players?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, max-flow

I want to build a model to help me build a team in fantasy premier league. There are two parts to the problem:

1) Predicting the player performances next week given the data for the last week and for the least season.

2) Using the result of the predictive model to build a team within a price of 100million euros.

For part 2), I was thinking of using either a 6D knapsack algorithm (2D for weight and number of items and the other 4 dimensions to make sure the appropriate number of players are picked from each category) or to use min cost max flow (not sure how I can add categories or restrict the number of players from each category).

For part 1) the only examples and papers I have come across either use models to predict whether or not a team will win or just classify the players as "good" or "bad". The second part of my problem requires that I predict a specific value for each player. At the moment I am thinking of using regression but I am not sure what kind of features I should use in this.